# Limit resources by process name

Tags: ubuntu, process

I would like to limit a process to 1% of the CPU and 150Mb using `cgroups`.

```
   1233 root      20   0 1087908 264116  90788 S   6,3   3,3 101:08.16 iamahungryprocess
```

Most of the manuals give information by PID or group. What is the correct way to do it if I have the name of the process?

Answer (score 0):

[cpulimit](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/cpulimit.1.html)
allows limiting by process name using the following parameters:

```
--exe=FILE
          name of the executable program file

-P, --path=PATH
          absolute path name of the executable program file
```

The `man` page also gives these examples:

```
# cpulimit -e foo -l 50
          limits the CPU usage of the process by acting on the executable program file

# cpulimit -P /usr/bin/foo -l 50
          same as -e but uses the absolute path name
```